# How do I hide the url bar in the WPA app generated for Android?

Tags: wpa

I created a PWA android app from https://www.pwabuilder.com/ The problem is that there is no option to hide the URL bar.
how do i hide url bar in app generated for andoid? I just want the site to be displayed.

The link below has a screenshot of the bar I want to hide in the WPA app.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YO0p.png

More details:
The https://www.pwabuilder.com/ system does not give you an option to hide the URL bar, but you can edit the "manifesto" file as shown in the screenshot of the link below:

https://prnt.sc/1h8hzgf

The manifest code is:

```
{
  "name": "Streaming Sou Power",
  "short_name": "Sou Power",
  "description": "Um salto an sua qualidade de vida",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "https://www.queroserpower.com/aulas/wp-content/uploads/sites/5/2021/07/logo-aplicativo-sou-power.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "https://www.queroserpower.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/cropped-cropped-Logo-Horizontal-Branco-163x54.png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ],
  "background_color": "#313131",
  "theme_color": "#313131",
  "display": "fullscreen",
  "orientation": "any",
  "start_url": "/aulas/?utm_source=superpwa&utm_medium=superpwa&utm_campaign=superpwa",
  "scope": "/aulas/",
  "screenshots": []
}
enter code here
enter code here
enter code here
```

Would it be possible to hide the URL bar through some editing in this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add digital asset links. This will make the address bar disappear from your app.

To add digital asset links, follow the [instructions outlined here](https://github.com/pwa-builder/CloudAPK/blob/master/Next-steps.md#1-deploy-assetlinksjson):

Your PWABuilder download will include a zip file that contains both your Android package (.aab) for uploading to the Store, an .apk file for testing on your Android phone or emulator, and also, a assetlinks.json file that needs to be uploaded to your server.

The asset links file proves domain ownership. Once you add that, the address bar will disappear from your app.

Comment: I understood. Thanks.
But how to add digital asset links to hide the bar?

Comment: It's explained in the readme. https://github.com/pwa-builder/CloudAPK/blob/master/Next-steps.md

Answer (score 0):

It didn't work for me with the assets of PWA images.You have to log in to the Google console and you can find the correct asset file in the settings.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).